# Remove the style attribute from a specific tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help for jQuery to remove styles in style tag.

```
<style>
    div.tab{backgroung:#666666;}
</style>
```

I need to empty this `div.tab` style or remove this `style` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to remove the `style` *element*. (Whether this is a feasible approach cannot be decided without knowing what problem it is supposed to solve.) For this, you need some kind of identification of the element, in CSS.

For example, if the `style` element is the first one among the `style` elements of a page, then you can use

```
var badStyle = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0];
badStyle.parentNode.removeChild(badStyle);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer well i am using style tag to be created using jquery ,in sharepoint but for every execution the style tag created again and again ,so, i thought before executing the jquery remove all style element tag.

Comment: This answers the question asked. If the question you meant to ask was something different, please ask a new question (illustrating it with some actual code; the description in the comment is very confusing).

Answer (score 0):

to remove particular style properties , you can try with `css()`
try this

```
 $('div.tab').css({'background':''});
```

to remove style statement from the tag use `attr`

```
 $('div.tab').attr( "style", "");  // .removeAttr('style')
```

or

```
 $('style').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

$('div.tab').removeClass('someClass');

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the style from the style tag using jquery.
However you can override the style using jquery for  the elements.

```
$('div.tab').css({'background':''});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove *all* the `style` elements, then use this `jQuery` :

```
$('style').remove();
```